# pydantic initialize new object with an existing object (fastapi)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I have a Base class, to get the values from the frontend. The user_id should comes from the `Depends(deps.get_current_user)` function.

**How can i initialize the new class CommentCreate now, with the values from CommentBase?**

**And is this the common use?**

I got it worked with the workaround `extra=Extra.allow` and `setattr(message,...)`

I think it should be something like:  `commentCreate = schemas.CommentCreate(**comment, user_id=current_user.id)`

```
class CommentBase(BaseModel, extra=Extra.allow):
    blog_id: int
    message: str


class CommentCreate(CommentBase):
    user_id: int
```

```
@router.post("/post/comment")
def post_comment_reply(
    message: schemas.CommentBase,
    current_user: models.User = Depends(deps.get_current_active_user),
    db: Session = Depends(deps.get_db),
):
    setattr(message, "user_id", current_user.id)
    print(message)
```

Comment: `**comment.dict()` would probably work fine, but I'd usually let the `user_id` not be part of the pydantic model at all, and give it separately to the service method that stores the comment object itself (`comment_service.add_comment(user_id, comment)`)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`dict`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict) method to achieve this.

something like :

`CommentCreate(user_id=current_user , **message.dict())`

Comment: Please add a reference link along with your answer.